# Difference between whole numbers and decimal numbers

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

Clearly, **whole numbers** specify *how many* elements there are in a collection while **decimal numbers** specify *how much* of a substance there is in a lump---but only after a **unit** of that substance has been chosen. But then whether we use a *whole number* or a *decimal number* depends on the chosen unit:

0.004 Kilometers is a whole number of meters, namely 4.

0.00004 Kilometers is a whole number of centimeters  namely 4,

But it gets worse: While

0.00004 KiloDollars is a whole number of centiDollars, namely 4?

can we really say that

0.004 KiloPeople is a whole number of Peoples, namely 4,

But then what about

0.00004 KiloPeople is a whole number of centiPeople, namely 4?

Where do you draw the line between *whole* and *decimal* and how do you *explain* it to *very raw beginning* students who want to *understand*?  (Saying that, *here*, 4 is really the decimal number 4.0 does not really help.)

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence's use of the word "clearly." I generally use *whole numbers* to refer to the counting numbers (including zero) and *decimal* to indicate a number that is written in its base 10 representation, often with a decimal point. So, e.g., if I wanted to refer to a number like 0.5, 0.333..., 0.12345..., but not e.g. 1, 2, 3, ..., then I might refer to it as a *non-integer decimal*, or say *a decimal that is not a whole number*.

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman I am more than willing to withdraw the word "clearly"---which I detest and which I used only to indicate that this was not what my question was about, but that would affect your comment. I also like your "integer decimal" / "non-integer decimal" distinction.

Comment: But, doesn't saying $4$ is the decimal number $4.0$ help? Every counting number is a decimal, but, not every decimal is a counting number. Perhaps the error is in thinking that only counting numbers can be used to count. As your examples point out, it depends what we're counting.

Comment: @ James S, Cook  Whole numbers are a few thousand years old and need not be written in the **Base 10 system**. **Decimal** on the other hand usually connotes something entirely different namely, originally, numbers less than 1 and eventually _whole numbers_ plus a _decimal number_. In fact, decimal numbers are usually intimately associated with the idea of _precision_ as in "Get more decimals". So, to say that 4, which evokes 4 people with 4.1 people being meaningless, is the same as 4., which evokes 4.0 dollars with 4.1 dollars being more precise, does not help at all.

Comment: Whole numbers have finite representations; decimals can be repeating or non-terminating.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche How is this related to the question which you obviously did not read else you would have noticed that it involves the interaction between the base TEN system and the METRIC system.

Comment: Say that 0.004 KiloPeople is the same as 3.99999... Peoples. Problem solved. (?)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins You caused me to edit my question so now you will see why the problem is _not_ solved: "4 people" lets us know we are talking about a whole number of people but "0.004 KiloPeople" gives us no immediate signal and, for said students, that opens a frightful abyss. And such beginners are not going to like "3.99999... Peoples" particularly given the way they interpret the "...".

Comment: What age / level of mathematical understanding should your communication support? Let me suggest you tag your question e.g primary-education or secondary-education

Comment: @Engelsmann I asked the question because many _adults_ have asked me.

Comment: That accounts for age but not for level of mathematical understanding. My reason for asking is to have you line out the kind of answer that would satisfy yor (and the folks asking you).

Comment: Some of my colleagues have zero understanding of mathematics but, oh boy, are they  great math teachers! Which of course you won't think answers your question. So think of perfectly reasonable people, say a car mechanics or a surgeon, both very good at what they are doing, who may or may not have taken math courses where of course they did not "understand" anything other than what to remember to pass, asking: how can "0.004 Kilometers, a decimal number, be the same as 4 meters, a whole number"? Which in turns begs the question which, gods forbid, I will not ask here: what is to "understand"?

Comment: -1. Question is based on faulty assumptions. OP said in May 27 comment was willing to take out faulty assumption but has not done so. Numerous questions included; specific question is unclear.

Comment: Aside (?): decimals are not *numbers*, they are *numeral* -- a system of notation. `4` is, for example, a way to write the whole number four in decimal notation.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins 1. I wrote "I am more than willing to withdraw the word "clearly"" but didn't for the reason given. 2l What "assumption" are you referring to?

Comment: @Hurkyl You are right of course. But "decimal number" is part of the common language: as engineers used to say, the _real_ real numbers are the decimal numbers.

Comment: The number 4 is a real real number. Really. It is also used to count 4 things. I fail to understand this discussion. Sorry I missed your comment a week back schremmer.

Comment: @ Hurkyl See (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Counting" (leading to counting numbers) is a special case (with ambiguities) of "measuring", where the role of "the measure/unit" is more visible. Obviously (I think) the natural unit implied in "counting" situations is some relevant-atomic unit (such as "whole, operational person", rather than not-so-functional smaller-part of a person).

That is, counting implicitly measures with unit the smallest/atomic feasible/operational measure (often so universally implicit that it is beyond discussion).

A fancier analogue arises when more advanced undergrads are first exposed to the idea that infinite sums (a.k.a. "series") fall under the umbrella of "integrals", but with "counting measure"... and that discrete sets have at least one natural regular, positive Borel measure, namely, the counting measure.

Comment: *1.* That is what I was alluding to in my opening sentence and so, of course, I agree and I like the particular tinge you are giving to it. *2.* But how do you respond to the very raw beginning students who ask "Why can't we say 0.04 DekaPeople since we can say 0.04 KiloPeople? Somehow, that 0.04 DekaPeople = 0.4 People and 0.04 KiloPeople = 40 People does not help: their view is that once we operate in the decimal-metric system, there should be no recourse to extraneous considerations and things should not depend on whether the "denominator" is  _People_ or _liters of milk_.

Comment: @schremmer, I'd argue that _without_ "recourse to extraneous considerations" the arithmetic still makes sense, sure, but relevance/applicability can sometimes suffer. Context matters.

Comment: Of course, context is essential as happens most of the time. These, though, are so-called developmental students and are very hard to get to take logic into consideration. But then, once they start, naturally, they get hung-up on things like that. I try to tell them that they will always be able to tell from the "denominator", to which they agree, but they still insist that "there ought to be a rule" independent of whether we are talking People of liters of milk. That is what I don't know how to answer.

Comment: @schremmer, you might tell them that not everything (even in math) can be reduced to a list of unambiguous rules. I realize there are various developmental situations, but, still, I try to assure students at all levels that they should _not_ suspend their own critical judgement... but/and that they have a responsibility for _using_ it, rather than just using magical thinking or invoking inexplicable "rules".

Comment: Here again, I agree of course. The problem I have is that for developmental students this is typical of their first logical, critical questions for which they expect (hope?) there is a logical answer: they see a pattern which then breaks down and want to know why as, presumably, they want to learn from that. I am not the one who chooses their questions but I would rather not risk discouraging them as it takes extremely little at this point for them to clam up.

Comment: My response to a question like "Why can't we say 0.04 DekaPeople [0.4 people]" is that we certainly *can* say something like that. E.g. Question: What is the population density in the Falkland Islands per square kilometer? Answer: 0.26 people. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkland_Islands)

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't we say "0.04 People" since we can say "0.04 KiloPeople"?

Some quantities (e.g., people) are discrete quantities and some (e.g., meters, dollars) are continuous quantities.

The following discussion is from [here](https://joelreyesnoche.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/theory-of-quantity/).  (I've emphasized the words "natural number" and "decimal.")

> **Classification of quantities**
>
> A quantity is either *discrete* or *continuous*. A discrete quantity is the magnitude of a countable set (one whose elements are “mutually separated and individually distinct”). Its numeral value is a **natural number** (“division into a quantity less than a unit cannot be considered”) and its unit is clear at the start. An example of a discrete quantity is “three boys.”
>
> A continuous quantity is the magnitude of a “continuum” (“a continuous entity which can be divided into any number of smaller parts” such that “any two such entities can be combined into a larger one”). Its numeral value (a **decimal** or a fraction) and its unit “have not been determined *a priori*.” An example of a continuous quantity is “three dollars.”
>
> A continuous quantity is either *extensive* or *intensive*. The former expresses breadth or magnitude (such as area or weight); the latter expresses quality or intensity (such as density or speed). An extensive quantity has additivity: the attribute of the union of two bodies is equal to the sum of the attributes of the two bodies. An intensive quantity does not have additivity. For example, the weight of two bodies is necessarily the sum of their weights, but the speed of two bodies is not necessarily the sum of their speeds.

The text is written for mathematics educators, but it can be reworded to be more easily understood by beginners.)

---

*My original answer (included here for context) which the OP pointed out did not address the intended question:*

Some quantities, such as, say, $1/3$ liter, have decimal representations ($0.\overline{3}$ liters) but no whole number representations.

Comment: What does this have to do with _my_ question?

Comment: Your question was "Where do you draw the line between *whole* and *decimal* and how do you *explain* it to *very raw beginning* students who want to *understand*?"  I am proposing that you draw the line when the decimal representation does not terminate and that this example should be clear to "very raw beginning" students.

Comment: @The very raw beginners I am dealing with have no idea of what a decimal may represent, let alone of a decimal representation that does not terminate. Besides, **1/3 liter of milk** is **1**, which is a whole number that _numerates_  the things _ denominated_ by **of which it takes 3 to make a liter of milk** so here is your whole number representation. In any case, that has little to do with the original question.

Comment: So how about $\sqrt{2}$ meters, the length of the hypotenuse of an isosceles right triangle with each leg of length $1$ meter?  Would you agree that it has a decimal representation but not a whole number representation?

Comment: Of course but what does it have to do with the original question? You are still answering a question _I never asked_. The question I asked turns around: Why can't we say "0.04 People" since we can say "0.04 KiloPeople"?

Comment: You may find a version of said distinction for mathematics non-educators at (http://freemathtexts.org/Standalones/RBAv6-2/1.pdf). But, indeed, the way I should have put the original question is ""How can a quantity of **People** be _extensive_ and a quantity of **KiloPeople** be _intensive_? And it is an oft-asked question! (By the way, 3 Dollars is a bit ambiguous because people often visualize 3 Dollar-bills.)

Comment: OOps, terrible mistake: I meant of course: How can a quantity of **People** be _discrete_ and a quantity of **KiloPeople** be _continuous_?

Comment: "How can a quantity of **People** be *discrete* and a quantity of **KiloPeople** be *continuous*?"  I suppose the answer is:  there is no such thing as "KiloPeople;" it cannot be continuous because it does not exist.

Comment: Of course there is! Just as in MegaPixels, GigaBucks, TeraBytes, etc. As I mentioned in the original question, where things get sticky is with, e.g. "Is 0.00004 KiloPeople a whole number of centiPeople, namely 4?"

Comment: I hope I didn't come on too hard but I have been facing this question from _students_ for many years without being able to come up with _any_  response. that the _students_ would accept as "*convincing*". I will post another one of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is largely a consequence of the fact that many people find the prefixes of the metric system (*kilo-*, *centi-*, etc.) unfamiliar, and find decimals (even terminating ones) less intuitive than the "vulgar fractions" they represent.

If somebody asked me "How can 0.004 Kilometers, a decimal number, be the same as 4 meters, a whole number"? (as the OP mentions in the comments below his question), I would respond with something like this:

> Are you also bothered by the fact that $1/2$ a dozen eggs, a fraction, is the same as 6 eggs, a whole number?

What would come next depends on the questioner's response.  But let's assume they respond with something like:  "Okay, I guess I get that.  But why can I say '0.04 kilopeople' but I can't say '0.04 people'?"  In that case, I would respond with:

> Are you also bothered by the fact that you can boil half a dozen eggs, but you can't boil half an egg?

The point of these responses, to be clear, is not to shut down the conversation with a zinger, but rather to bring to the surface what the underlying issues are:  "1 kilopeople" means the same as "1000 people", and you can have half of a thousand people in just the same way that you can have half of a dozen eggs.  On the other hand you *can't* have $1/7$ of a thousand people, in exactly the same way that you can't have $1/7$ of a dozen eggs.

Comment: My problem with a question like "Why can't we say '0.04 People'", is that it seems to me like we certainly *can* say that. For example, it could be the population density per square kilometer in a certain region. In fact: 0.04 people *actually is* exactly the population density (per km^2) in the Svalbard and Jan Mayen islands of Norway. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_population_density).

Comment: @mweiss Developmental students who _begin_ to ask questions do not like being answered with a question. They would dismiss your "Are you also bothered ..." as a "teacher trick". Later, in the discussion, of course, they would  have no objection to your line of reasoning and would in fact go along with it. However, what I think their question is really about, as  I commented to Paul Garrett, is: "once we operate in the decimal-metric system, there should be no recourse to extraneous considerations and things should not depend on whether the "denominator" is People or liters of milk."